# How to map chmod access permissions to an integer

Tags: permissions, chmod

I came across a piece of code where chmod permissions are getting mapped to an integer.

```
33204 // -rw-rw-r--
36863 // -rwsrwsrwt
36855 // -rwsrwSrwt
36799 // -rwSrwsrwt
36351 // -rwsrwsrwx
36343 // -rwsrwSrwx
```

How are these permissions mapped to an integer number?

I am trying to find what permissions these numbers `33261, 41453` map to?
I looked at various links, but I could find one that converts permissions into a number. Can someone help me with the conversion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They only make "sense" in octal. Here's the first line using [one of my programs](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:hex) to convert:

```
$ hex 33204
33204: 33204 0100664 0x81b4 text "\201\264" utf8 \350\206\264
```

The **`0100664`** means it's a regular file with read/write (user), read/write (group) and read-only (other).  The `chmod` manual pages should mention this, but the first bit (the `S_IFREG` value) is not mentioned — even by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) — as often as the other flags.  Here's an example from a header:

```
#define S_IFMT  00170000
#define S_IFSOCK 0140000
#define S_IFLNK  0120000
#define S_IFREG  0100000
#define S_IFBLK  0060000
#define S_IFDIR  0040000
#define S_IFCHR  0020000
#define S_IFIFO  0010000
#define S_ISUID  0004000
#define S_ISGID  0002000
#define S_ISVTX  0001000
```

Further reading:

- [understanding and decoding the file mode value from stat function output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055634/understanding-and-decoding-the-file-mode-value-from-stat-function-output)

Comment: Thanks! From a numerical value is there an easy way to get the corresponding permission too?

Comment: yes - but I don't offhand know of a standalone program to use as an example.